# Partial derivative and total derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

so i have a function  $ f: R  \rightarrow  R $ and a vector
 $ \overrightarrow{r} $ given. 
So i found this, but i don't understand why this is working.

$ \frac{\partial f(r)  x_{3} }{\partial  x_{2} } - \frac{\partial f(r)  x_{2} }{\partial  x_{3} } =  \frac{d f(r)}{d r} ( \frac{ x_{2}  }{r}  x_{3} -  \frac{ x_{3}  }{r}  x_{2}) $ with $ r = \mid\overrightarrow{r}\mid  $

Comment: If you use $r^2=x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+x_{3}^2$ you should be able to calculate the partial derivatives of $r$ w.r.t the $x_i$. Then you need "function of a function" aka chain rule.

Comment: Thank you! Now i understand:)